# How to generate a 100 HD wallets, what the proper derivation path would be?

Tags: wallet, address, getsignaturesforaddress

I'm using `solana/web3.js`

This derivation phrase is used by TrustWallet

```
m/44'/501'/0'
```

How would I generate a 100 wallets? One would have thought I could add a counter to it:

```
m/44'/501'/0'/0
m/44'/501'/0'/1
m/44'/501'/0'/2
....
m/44'/501'/0'/99
```

But this would throw an exception "invalid derivation path".

**How could it possibly be invalid?** Can't it be anything whatsoever? As long as  it's in this format -- `m/44'/{a}'/{b}'/{c}/....../{x}`.

Then what derivation path would one use to generate a 100 wallets by iteration?

Comment: This might sound silly, but can you add the trailing `'` to make it `m/44'/501'/0'/0'` instead of `m/44'/501'/0'/0`?

Comment: Would not be the article like this bringing the answer? https://moviendo.me/solana-wallet-derivation-path-and-multiple-accounts.html

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason you're interested in setting the derivation path?

With `solana/web3.js` you can use the `Keypair` object to create new keypairs (wallets)

```
import {Keypair} from '@solana/web3.js'
let wallets = []
for (var i=0;i<100;i++)
    wallets.push(new Keypair.generate())
```

Comment: how would you then restore a KeyPair if you happen to lose access to its private key?

Comment: `Is there a specific reason you're interested in setting the derivation path?` - yes.

Comment: `how would you then restore a KeyPair if you happen to lose access to its private key?` You dont, you need the seed or the private key, to restore.